# How to debug nodelet manager?

Tags: ros, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, ros-indigo, nodelet-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,everyone
I am a beginner of ros , and now I want to debug my code which has one nodelet manager and four nodelets. I add  `launch-prefix="gdb -ex run --args"` to nodelet manager in `.launch` file,and also add `-g` to `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` in `CmakeLists.txt` ,but the xterm tells that no debug symbols was found.Could anyone tell me where i am wrong or give me some directions about the details to debug nodelet manager?
Thank you very much!

Your Sincerely

tyjin

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307145/how-to-debug-nodelet-manager?/) by [tyjin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38264/tyjin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-10-30

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-10-30**:
Do you want to debug `nodelet_manager` *itself*, or your nodelets?

If the former: you'll have to build `nodelet_manager` in your workspace with debug symbols enabled.

If the latter: just make sure to build your own nodelets with debug enabled.

**Comment by [tyjin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38264/tyjin/) on 2018-10-30**:
Hi gvdhoorn,
Thank you very much.
I want to debug nodelet_manager so that I can step through the code and set breakpoints at some line of code.I tried many options to enable debug symbols but failed. So please can you tell me what to add in CmakeLists.txt to make debug symbols enabled.

tyjin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I want to debug nodelet_manager so that I can step through the code and set breakpoints at some line of code

If you really want to debug `nodelet_manager` itself, you'll have to build it from sources in your Catkin workspace. The default Indigo binaries do not come with debug symbols, so that is why `gdb` tells you this.

(I'm assuming you are using ROS Indigo here, as that is what you tagged the question with)

To build it from source, clone [ros/nodelet_core](https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core) into your Catkin workspace (make sure to have the `indigo-devel` branch checked out) and make sure to install all dependencies (using `rosdep install ..`). Update the `CMakeLists.txt` to enable debug symbols and then build the workspace.

Now `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` and *then* run your launch file.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-10-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tyjin](https://answers.ros.org/users/38264/tyjin/) on 2018-10-30**:
Hi,gvdhoorn,thank you for telling me the reason of this problem i am confused with for a long time.I will follow your advice to try it.Thank you very much again !

tyjin